# Segments overlapping issue in stacked column with multiple series Highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to create a stacked column chart with multiple series.
As shown in the Highcharts Img below, the segments overlapping occurs and data is not displayed properly.
This situation occurs when the series data has too much varying values (like 25489, 1116, 94, etc).

So is there any way to modify y-Axis scales or y-Axis intervals or to increase the pixel value between the small values y-Axis intervals only so that there will be enough space to render all the small values segments  properly.?

Highcharts Img:-

[image: Highcharts Img]

Comment: Have you considered to use the `logarithmic` yAxis type? API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type

Comment: I have already used Sebastian ..It is not solving this problem.

Comment: May I see a reproduction of your issue with sample data?